# Index setted but undefined index

Tags: php, session, indexing, undefined

I'm in a ambiguous situation.
Here's the concerned code:
http://prntscr.com/9edm4j

```
public function verifyReply($reponse)
{
    $qr = $this->mStopBOT;
    if(isset($_SESSION["stopBOT"]))
    {
        if($_SESSION["stopBot"] === false)
        {
            $_SESSION["stopBOT"] = true;
            if($qr[$_SESSION["stopBOTq"]][1] == $reponse)
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And here is the problem:
http://prntscr.com/9ednwm

PHP Notice:  Undefined index: stopBot in /home/*************/public_html/inc/classes/Security.inc.php on line 92

**The isset() function returns true**, but when I use the function, it says that the *index is undefined!* ?

Regards and Thanks in Advance

Comment: Post the relevant code and problem-descriptions here , don't use links (they might get stale in the future, while this question is here to help others as well as yourself).

Comment: what are you doing man? check your session index name, you are doing spelling mistake.. StopBOT and StopBot

Comment: Ok ;) I'll do that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking if `$_SESSION['stopBOT']` is set but then use `$_SESSION['stopBot']`

Note the case difference, stopBOT vs stopBot

Comment: Of course ! :D I didn't see x) Thank you !

Comment: @Loio: Than you must watch Now you see me.. :)

Comment: @devpro My nickname begins with a capital i, not a L...  Of course, It's a stupid situation.